# Is it possible to establish Dharmarājya (Rāmarājya) in Kaliyuga?

Tags: dharma, kali-yuga

It is often described in various Śāstras that the Kaliyuga will be an age rife with Adharma.

Does that imply that it is completely impossible to establish Dharmarājya or Rāmarājya in Kaliyuga?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not impossible for Dharmarājya or Rāmarājya to be established in Kaliyuga. Rather, Yugas are created by Kings.

Manusmṛti 9.301 states:

> कृतं त्रेतायुगं चैव द्वापरं कलिरेव च । राज्ञो वृत्तानि सर्वाणि राजा हि
> युगमुच्यते ॥ ३०१ ॥
>
> kṛtaṃ tretāyugaṃ caiva dvāparaṃ kalireva ca | rājño vṛttāni sarvāṇi
> rājā hi yugamucyate || 301 ||
>
> The actions of the king constitute the ‘Kṛta’, the ‘Tretā’, the
> ‘Dvāpara’ and the ‘Kali’ cycles; as it is the king that is called the
> ‘cycle.’

In the Udyogaparva of the Mahābhārata, Kuntī too makes a similar statement to her son Yudhiṣṭhira:

> The penal code properly applied by the ruler, maketh the four orders adhere to their respective duties, and leadeth to an acquisition (by the ruler himself) of virtue (profit, and salvation). When the king properly abideth by the penal code, without making any portion of it a dead letter, then that best of periods called the Krita Yuga setteth in. **Let not this doubt be thine, viz., whether the era is the cause of the king, or the king the cause of the era, for (know this to be certain that) the king is the cause of the era. It is the king that createth the Krita, the Treta, or the Dwapara age. Indeed, it is the king that is the cause of also the fourth Yuga (viz., the Kali). That king who causeth the Krita age to set in, enjoyeth heaven exceedingly. That king who causeth the Treta age to set in, doth enjoy heaven but not exceedingly. For thus causing the Dwapara age to set in, a king enjoyeth heaven according to his due. The king, however, who causeth the Kali age to set in, earneth sin exceedingly. Thereupon, that king of wicked deeds resideth in hell for countless years. Indeed, the king's sins affect the world, and the world's sins affect him.** Observe thou those kingly duties of thine that befit thy ancestry.

Therefore, it is certainly possible to establish Dharmarājya or Rāmarājya in Kaliyuga, depending on whether the King abides by Dharma. However, chances of an appearance of such a king do remain very slim in Kaliyuga.

Comment: You answer your own questions. Why?. Why did you asked this question.

Comment: @DarkKnight maybe OP is presenting two views in his answer. Manusmriti saying it's not possible, while one from Mahābhārata saying yes. Is the era cause of king or is the king cause of era? Q&A style.

Comment: @DarkKnight What is wrong with that? Its not against the rules of the site to answer your own question. Also, if you notice, before asking a new question, there's an option to answer your own question together.

Comment: @Rāmadāsa yes you are correct but my point is if you know the answer then why to ask. By looking at the timeing of your question and answers, it was almost the same or exactly the same, when I saw you answered your question the time on both was 21 minutes. (1/2)

Comment: @Rāmadāsa there is nothing wrong with it but I was little surprised. That you ask and Answers in less than 5 minutes. Any way I like you answer.

Comment: @DarkKnight Thank you but I'm not the first one to post Q/A simultaneously. There have been many posts like these in the past.

Comment: @DarkKnight https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.165790459.492985677.1614588048-523239458.1614004073

Comment: @Rāmadāsa OK bro no problem

Comment: Which specific "the King", it refers to in here? I guess at any time particular there can be several Kings on the *bhuloka* (the Earth) simultaneously? So, how does *"the kingeth causes the age"*, isn't there a natural decline in the dharma itself with each falling age?

Comment: @Vivikta There's no specific king involved. Country A ruled by an Adharmic King can be Kali-Yuga while Country B ruled by a Dharmik King can be Satya Yuga.